# Jboss EAP 6.1 spring modules class loading not working

Tags: spring, jboss-eap-6

I have a spring integration project deployed in jboss as a WAR file.
The project uses maven and structured to support any type of archival War or Jar.

However, the dependencies of the project (all spring jars and custom jars) should be externalized

The reason would be that, later there would be 100s of Spring Integration flows would be deployed and if we have the jars in WEB-INF/libs the size of WAR grows to ~ 50MB. As we have abstracted much of our functionality in a seperate jar (would be added as dependency to my spring integration project), Externalization will result in reducing the WAR file to ~ 5 KB.

I do not have a web.xml and use the WebInitializer for loading the context (Which is part of my common functionality and added as dependency)

Below is what I have tried with JBOSS.

1. Created a module com.xxx.yyy and added all my spring/third party and custom jars as resources.
2. Added the dependency to manifest file. (This did not work)
3. Added the **jboss-deployment-structure.xml** to my war **WEB-INF** (did not work)
4. If I give the wrong module name its throws errors as module
   not found.

The war gets deployed, but not initialized. If I have the dependencies in my WEB-INF/lib, everything works as expected.

Below is the jboss deployment structure xml that I used.

> ```
>     <jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
>     <deployment>
>         <dependencies>
>             <module name="com.xxx.yyy" services="import" >
>                 <imports>
>                         <include path="META-INF**"/>
>                       <include path="org**"/>
>                 </imports>
>             </module>
>         </dependencies>
>     </deployment>
> </jboss-deployment-structure>
> ```

Here is the expectation,

1. Externalize the Jar dependencies.
2. Import the dependencies to my war(manifest or jboss-deployment-structure.xml)
3. Should be used Spring Service should be initialize.
4. The deployed war should be working as it does if the libraries are
   in WEB-INF

Please help...

Comment: Please let me know how you solved this issue, I am facing same on wildfly 12

Answer (score 0):

With JBOSS EAP 6, Its not possible to deploy the war without a web.xml, But such is possible only with tomcat or by using spring boot.
Also, to address this problem, we had to create a dummy web.xml and use jboss modules to load dependencies.